# How to move a partition to the beginning of a drive

Tags: partition, dd

Say you have some drive `/dev/sda` that is 1TB in size. There is a partition `/dev/sda2` of size 750GB at the end of the drive, and there is 250GB of unallocated space at the beginning of the drive. How would you go about moving this partition to the beginning of the drive (the unnallocated space then being at the end of the drive)?

I was thinking something like `dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/sda`, but that doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: you could use an appropriate `seek=N` value, to start the output to the beginning of where an `sda1` would start

Comment: When you manipulate partitions like that, you obviously have a backup. So, just recreate the partition table on /dev/sda and restore the backup to the partition at the beginning.

Comment: Is drive gpt or old MBR(msdos)? Your dd proposal will destroy all data as parts of sda2 will get overwritten by other parts. You can just use gparted to move partition left. If much data that can take a very long time and any interruption will destroy data.